# JAVA: How do i use user inputs in a different method from the one in which it was created?

Tags: java, methods, static-methods

I'm making a simple program that takes 2 scores from a user, does some basic sums with he scores and provides the user with their "fitness age". The problem is, i cannot use the data from the user as it is in different method from the calculation. I have tried to copy what other code on this website looks like but i think i might have messed up my own code, any help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Health {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int in = firstScore();
        int in = secondScore();
        revealAge(in);
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void firstScore() {

        Scanner firstScores = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What score did you recieve in your first exercise out of 40?");

        int score1 = firstScores.nextInt();

        return score1;

    }

    public static void secondScore() {

        Scanner secondScores = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What score did you recieve in your second exercise out of 40?");

        int score2 = secondScores.nextInt();

        return score2;

    }

    public static void revealAge(int score1, int score2) {

        int average = (score1 + score2) / 2;

        int fitnessAge = (((average * 8) / 5) + 10);

        System.out.println("Your average score is " + average + ".");

        System.out.println("Your PC Fit age is" + fitnessAge + ".");

        return;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `in`? Assign the return value to another variable and pass those into `revealAge`

Comment: A `void` method returns no value, change your return type from `void` to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `int` in both `secondScore()` and `firstScore()` methods. And you have one name(`in`) for many variable declarations in your `main` method. Made some modifications to your code as per to the problems I stated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Health {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int in1 = firstScore();
        int in2 = secondScore();
        revealAge(in1, in2);
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static int firstScore() {

        Scanner firstScores = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What score did you recieve in your first exercise out of 40?");

        int score1 = firstScores.nextInt();

        return score1;

    }

    public static int secondScore() {

        Scanner secondScores = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What score did you recieve in your second exercise out of 40?");

        int score2 = secondScores.nextInt();

        return score2;

    }

    public static void revealAge(int score1, int score2) {

        int average = (score1 + score2) / 2;

        int fitnessAge = (((average * 8) / 5) + 10);

        System.out.println("Your average score is " + average + ".");

        System.out.println("Your PC Fit age is " + fitnessAge + ".");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems:

- Methods `firstScore()` and `secondScore()` are both defined to return nothing (that's what the `void` does in the method definition) - based on how you're using them, you probably want to return `int` instead.
- You're trying to define `in` twice in your `main` method. You need to name these variables differently. How about `int firstScore` and `int secondScore`?
- Calling `revealAge` from your `main` method should pass both those parameters, not just one.

Fixing these issues should help your code compile.  I strongly recommend stepping through some java tutorials, so that errors like this become more obvious to you in the future.

- Nit: your formatting is rather wonky. Look into best practices for formatting java code.